# How do I copy a file from one rails application to aws ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-web-services

I want to copy a file from my one rails application to a remote/ another application hosted on an aws ec2 instance. I have my security group TCP ports 21 and 21 open for ssh and sftp. But I'm not able to figure out any way to do it. I've tried `scp` so far and, it does not work.

I tried this:

```
scp -i ec2-keypair.pem myfile.txt ubuntu@my-public-ec2-ip:/home/ubuntu/my_new_file.txt
```

It prompts this: `Using /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334` and exit. But file transfer doesn't happen. What could be the possible issue??

And also if, you know any better solution to do the same then, please help me with your knowledge. Thanks

**EDIT** : It would be great if, the solution is available in `ruby` or `ruby on rails`. Cause ultimately I have to transfer a file from one rails application to another.

**EDIT** : When I do `scp -v -i ~/.ec2/ec2-keypair.pem Gemfile.lock ubuntu@175.41.140.84:/home/ubuntu/apps/` I get this: http://pastie.org/3613259

and  see here: http://pastie.org/3613269 for more verbose output with `-vvv`

Comment: Never seen such error message. Can you SSH to this Instance?

Comment: Yes, I am able to ssh to both ec2 instances. But scp doesn't happen.. :'(

Comment: Add some debug log on your command

Comment: How do I do that?? any pointers??

Comment: The fact that you're getting a ruby version from RVM may just be an artifact of switching to a directory having an `.rvmrc` file -- I doubt it's relevant.  scp is just a wrapper for ssh, so if you can ssh, scp should work.  To debug use `scp -v ...` (and if I recall, using `-vvv` gets you more verbose output).  I'll bet there's a permissions issue ... just a guess.

Comment: Oh, and once you get it working from the command line, use ruby's `system` or `exec` methods (the former spawns a sub-shell) to call the scp from within Rails.  Keep in mind that if you're doing this operation from the context of a web application, you'll have the permissions of the web user.

Comment: @tharrison Thanks for the options. I have updated the log I'm getting when I do `scp`. Guessing it has to do with `debug1: Roaming not allowed by server` on line 29 in first pastie. If it's a permission issue then, why I can't see anything related to it in the log??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this thread, and the last item *might* be relevant. http://centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=30515&forum=42

(btw, ssh -vvv will get you debug level 3, with even more inscrutable details).

So to be sure, the most common problem is that the permissions on the .ssh directory (on both local and remote hosts) somehow get overly permissive and ssh will refuse to use the credentials.  Perms on the `.ssh` directory should be `rwx` for user only (octal `chmod 700`), `rw` for user on the private key and .pem keypairs, and group/all readable for other files.

```
drwx------  11 tharrison  staff   374 Mar  1 16:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 79 tharrison  staff  2686 Mar  8 10:43 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 tharrison  staff   128 Aug 16  2010 .ssh-agent
-rw-r--r--   1 tharrison  staff   132 Dec 29 14:42 config
-rw-------   1 tharrison  staff  1675 Apr 20  2009 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@  1 tharrison  staff   405 Apr 20  2009 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 tharrison  staff  2805 Mar  5 08:33 known_hosts
-rw-------@  1 tharrison  staff  1693 Apr 27  2011 my-aws-keypair.pem
```

SSH is (properly) paranoid about what it will send to any log -- it doesn't want to give away any hints about what is or is not working as those hints could be used to discover vulnerabilities, etc.  So the logs can be helpful ... occasionally.

But I am not sure any of this is right, because I think you said you're able to log in successfully from the command line using ssh, and that scp doesn't work -- this kind of rules out ssh authentication issues (as I said, scp is really just ssh), which is why it's worth making sure that the user you're logging in as remotely has proper permissions to write the file to the location you're sending it.

Maybe try `ssh -i mykeypair.pem myuser@myremote.host 'touch ~/foo'`  All values starting "my" need to be replaced with the correct values, e.g. `mykeypair.pem` will need to have the path and name of the keypair you use to log in.  If this works, it will create a file named foo in myuser's home directory on the server myremote.host -- log in using ssh without the command and check -- then you have proper permissions, at least to that directory.  Now try to the real directory.

If it fails there, then check that all the directories in the path are group-x or all-x and the target directory is group or all rwx.

EDIT: corrected test ssh command and expanded on procedure and clarified.

Comment: @tharrion  Sorry for the late reply :) I tried `ssh -i mykeypair.pem mylocal ubuntu@myremote -c "touch ~/foo"` but it didn't work!! I'd replaced mylocal to localhost:3000 and it was trying to access remote database it seems which doesn't exist on local. And turned up with error: `db_name.server_name` not found.

Comment: Oops, my error on the ssh command -- multiple errors (blush), should have been `ssh -i mykeypair.pem myuser@myremote.host 'touch ~/foo'` -- this runs the command `touch ~/foo` on the host `myremote.host` as user `myuser` using the credentials found in the local file `mykeypair.pem`.  My errors from first example: 1) don't need `mylocal`, 2) don't need `-c`, and 3) use single quotes around the command so your local shell will not interpret the `~` to mean your local home directory. The correct values for all of the "my" placeholders will need to be replaced with ones right for your system.

Comment: I updated my answer with corrected ssh, and some clarifications.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response :) This command: `ssh -i path_to_mykeypair.pem myuser@myremote.host 'touch ~/foo'`  is still not working I have pasted the verbose output I get with option `-v` here: http://pastie.org/3639924 Thanks :-)

Comment: Later I had tried `touch ~/foo` on the server after ssh and it's working fine i.e. I could see a file with name **foo**.

Comment: Hey!! That command worked!! Please don't mind the comments I made above. So, permissions seems to have no issue I guess. However I tried `scp -vv -i path_to_mykeypair.pem /Gemfile.lock ubuntu@my-remote.host:/Gemfile.lock` for test. But it didn't work. Here is the pastie with `-vv` option: http://pastie.org/3640002

Comment: Trace shows authentication was successful.  Is `/Gemfile.lock` accurate?  This means scp should look in your machine's root filesystem `/` -- I would expect to find the file underneath the `app` directory of your project (which is probably at `/User/yourname/path-to-project/app/Gemfile.lock`).  Likewise on the remote host.  `~/` means "user's home directory" which will certainly be writable by the user.  `/` means "filesystem root" which is most likely _not_ writable.  Use `~/`, or better yet, the full path for both local and remote systems, and it will work.

Comment: Yes, that /Gemfile.lock is present in the directory. This issue is screwing me like anything. I guess there is no fix to it. I'll confirm this as an answer in a day. Keeping it open just to get few more ideas. Thanks for your time and help :)